# Using Python to overwrite SPSS variable

Tags: python, spss

My SPSS dataset contains two variables with names `time1` and `time2` and labels `time1` and `time2` respectively. Eventually, I want to use Python to read the variables and modify them. As a simple test, I am trying to replace every entry of `time1` with `"hello"`. This is the SPSS syntax I am using:

```
begin program python.
import spss, spssdata

data = spssdata.Spssdata(indexes=["time1"], accessType="w")

for row in data:
    data.setvalue("time1", "hello")
    data.CommitCase()

data.CClose()
end program.
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Warning: An open Cursor was detected while exiting a program block.
>   The Cursor has been closed.  Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 5, in     File
>   "C:\PROGRA~1\PREDIC~1\PSIMAG~1\5\IBM\SPSS\STATIS~1\25\PYTHON\Lib\site-
>   packages\spssdata\spssdata.py", line 467, in setvalue 
>       index = [varspec[0] for varspec in  self.newvars].index(var)  ValueError: 'time1' is not in list

What am I missing here? Thank you.

My variables:

[image: My variables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to overwrite data using Python using the `spssdata` module becuase it uses the `Cursor` object from the `spss` module, which cannot overwrite variables. It is possible to create a new variable and set its values using Python. You can then also delete the old variable and rename the new variable to the same name as the old one.

From *Programming and Data Management for IBM SPSS Statistics 23: A Guide for IBM SPSS Statistics and SAS Users*, page 167:

> write mode allows you to add new variables (and their case values) to the active dataset